# keep context within BackboneJS view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a shorter more elegant way to keep context within BackboneJS view?

```
    this.$el.find(this.itemViewContainer).sortable("destroy").sortable({
        connectWith:'.tasks',
        delay:140,
        revert:200,
        items:'li:not(.locked)',
        placeholder:'ui-state-highlight',
        start:_.bind(function (event, ui){this._sortStart(event, ui);}, this),
        receive:_.bind(function (event, ui){this._sortReceive(event, ui);}, this),
        stop:_.bind(function (event, ui){this._sortStop(event, ui);}, this)
    });
```

I am reffering to the:

- start event
- receive even
- stop event

it is important that: this, event and ui will be passed to the inner view event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [_.bindAll](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) to lock this to the view in your callbacks:

> **bindAll**  _.bindAll(object, [*methodNames])
>   Binds a number of methods on the object, specified by methodNames, to be run in the
>   context of that object whenever they are invoked. Very handy for
>   binding functions that are going to be used as event handlers, which
>   would otherwise be invoked with a fairly useless this. If no
>   methodNames are provided, all of the object's function properties will
>   be bound to it.

and you could use it like this

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, '_sortStart', '_sortReceive', '_sortStop');

        this.$el.sortable("destroy").sortable({
            items: 'li:not(.locked)',
            start: this._sortStart,
            receive: this._sortReceive,
            stop:this._sortStop
        });
    },

    _sortStart: function(event, ui) {
    },
    _sortReceive: function(event, ui) {
    },
    _sortStop: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/wAAZ5/

Comment: I don't even bother passing the method names, I just always do `_.bindAll(this)` in the parent class of all my views and call it done. Views are object oriented stateful instances, so it makes sense to have their functions treated as OO methods instead of pure functions. Binding them all makes it harder to accidentally forget one when you add new methods and introduce bugs that way.

Comment: @PeterLyons - do you know if your approach has a performance hit?

Comment: Yes. It will slow your application down by 0.0000000000000321%.

Comment: @Guy A quick perf test shows a performance hit http://jsperf.com/underscore-bindall but that will only matter if you create thousands of views and you have to balance that against the gains Peter listed.

Comment: @nikoshr Is that a performance hit compared to not doing bindAll at all, or compared to binding all your View's methods specifically by name?  Really wish I'd come across this post 12 hours ago, I'd have slept a lot better last night.

Comment: @sam The hit was _.bindAll(obj) vs _.bindAll(obj, 'method'), but since _.bindAll(obj) is now disallowed, the point is moot:) Anyway, use _.bindAll on the least methods you can