# backbone.js this context is lost in event functions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm kind of new to backbone and have a question. It seems like when an event in my view is fired, I lose the context to "this".  How can I preserve this or get the original "this" for the model.  Here is an example:

```
var MyListView = MyDBView.extend({
   initialize: function(options){

    },
    render: function() {
       //stuff here.  I can access this.options here

    },
  dialogResponseYes: function(e){
      //try to get this.options and options is undefined as this has changed to another element (a button)
   }

});
```

So, how do I get the original context of this?

Comment: What do you want `this` to point at? The view?

Comment: Yes.  Also, I would like to declare public properties in the MyListView class that would be accessible to all functions.  But to do this, I would need to be able keep "this" the same context for all methods and functions

Comment: possible duplicate of [keep context within BackboneJS view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233979/keep-context-within-backbonejs-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using events object to bind events to your view like here  http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents everything should be ok, otherwise u can hardly bind them to your view using `_.bindAll`

```
initialize: function(options){
_.bindAll(this, "dialogResponseYes");
    },
```

or

```
var MyListView = MyDBView.extend({
   initialize: function(options){

    },
    events: {
        'click div': 'dialogResponseYes' //example
    },
    render: function() {


    },
    dialogResponseYes: function(e){

    }

});
```

Comment: I did the first option and that did it!  Thanks